# Peticiones CURLPhp con tiempo de espera

Tags: php, api, curl

Estoy trabajando sobre una integración a una API de una plataforma de ecommerce, cada cierto tiempo necesito obtener el stock de mi tienda que está en ésta plataforma para actualizar las cantidades y quitar de existencia los productos que ya están descontinuados. Las especificaciones de la API que ellos proporcionan, indica que:
Los productos se obtienen en peticiones "paginadas" donde cada página me envía solo 50 productos a la vez.
Por cuestiones de "rendimiento" sugieren no enviar mas de 10 peticiones a la vez.

El código de la petición::::

```html
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.tevende/api/product-stocks/stores-and-warehouses/123456/product-versions/null/p/$p",
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
                CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
                CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
                CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
                CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => false,
                CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
                CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                    "Authorization: Bearer <<mi token>>"
                ),
            ));
```

Entonces, ¿cómo hago para enviar 10 peticiones, esperar, enviar las siguientes 10 y así sucesivamente?hasta obtener todo el stock. 
(El stock real son unos 35000 productos)

Comment: se me ocurre que podrías hacer un ciclo de 0 a 9 por ejemplo, pero haciendo eso, no obtendrías el total stock, no tienes opciones de ir a buscar el stock de los productos que estas tocando ?

Comment: @Elias Catalan si, cuando es para actualizar, pero en un primer momento es para obtener toda la información, es un proceso que no se haría todos los días, pero si hay que hacerlo en ciertas fechas

Comment: Cuanto tiempo recomienda tu proveedor de servicio el consumo de 10 peticiones ?

Comment: @EliasCatalan no lo especifica

Comment: disculpa por la demora, podrías tratar de implementar un cron el cual ejecute tu petición según la restricción que especificas, el cron lo puedes programar para que se ejecute a un tiempo considerado para no sobrecargar los servicios.

Comment: @EliasCatalan gracias